# word based learning similar to what is done in mnist

Tags: machine-learning

I am fairly new to this field and I have a use case where I would like to classify the type of a cloth by its attribute information(like descriptions of its length, width, height, cloth type etc etc). If you look at the famous Fashion MNIST dataset, they use images to classify the type of cloth into 10 known labels. Similarly, I would like to use lot of words that describe the clothing(referring to its label) instead of having images. 
Is this possible? Could some one advice on what machine learning approach can I take do this?

Comment: I am sorry. I have no idea how better to ask this question. The question I asked is my exact doubt.